# google-drive-sdk Push Gmail Attachments to GDrive when sending mail to internal resources

Tags: gmail, google-drive-api

It would be nice to automatically push file attachments to GDrive when sending file attachments to users in the same domain. Then send the GDrive link url instead.
Want this to be transparent to the sender
Think we can handle this with the existing get and insert api's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it probably would be possible with the Drive API, though I would more likely achieve this using Google Apps Script which supports GMail and Google Drive.